# Unparseable date Exception after trying to format a date

Tags: android

I'm getting information from xml file and the data is showing perfectly , in the xml file there is field for date and the date is formatted as following : "2020-08-01T18:45:00+00:00" , but the problem is that i want to only convert it to HH:mm to only get the hour and minutes , i tried to do so using simpleDateformat but it keeps showing me the Unparseable date exception .

- This is the exception

`Parse Exception : Unparseable date: "2020-08-01T18:45:00+00:00"`

- This the code to format my date

```
val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
     try {
         val toDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date)
         holder.livescoresrowslayoutBindingImpl.matchModel!!.match.date = simpleDateFormat.format(toDate!!)
     }catch (e : ParseException){
         Log.d("TAG","Parse Exception : " + e.message)
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this date string is always of the same format, you could truncat it(using substring metod for example) and remove characters for year, month an so on, so your are left with "18:45" and then you can use your existing code.

Comment: Yeah i thought about doing that as well since my date is the same format but i'm curious to know why it is not possible to parse it , thank you

Comment: So basically you use the SimpleDateFormat to convert string varialble into a date variable and to do so you provide a pattern, how the SimpleDateFormat parser should interpret each character in this string. So now this pattern is "HH:mm" and strings that would be successfully parsed should be of this kind like "23:15". Here you have much longer string with different things in it so you would have to provide different pattern for the parser.

Comment: Substring worked for me but ill try to investigate the other one more , thank you